# My AWS VPN setup results in no traffic working when connecting

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, amazon-vpc

I crossposted this to stackoverflow here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62585272/my-aws-vpn-setup-results-in-no-traffic-working-when-connecting in the hope of finding a solution...
Apologies.

I have created a VPN to our VPC but when I connect to it from my machine, nothing works - neither Internet, nor can I reach VPN-internal endpoints.

I added public `dns-servers` and `split-tunnel=enabled` to the configuration.

The VPN is set to

```
`Client IPv4 CIDR 10.10.0.0/16`
```

An association has been added (line from AWS console):

```
cvpn-assoc-<id>     subnet-<id>    cvpn-endpoint-<id> ￼     Associated     sg-<id>
```

There are two authorization rules (one allowing everything until I get it working)

The route table looks like this (was automatically added via the assoc):

```
cvpn-endpoint-<id>  10.1.0.0/16 subnet-<id>  Nat      associate ￼    Active      Default Route
```

This RT is the only thing which looks odd. In the VPC, the subnet has a definition of `10.1.0.0/24` - but the automatic association sets it to `10.1.0.0/16`. But there's actually no way to set it to `10.1.0.0/24` in the routing table, doing so results in an error about the range being invalid.

I also tried creating the VPC with a client IP CIDR of `10.10.0.0/24` but then it errored saying it must at least be `/22`.

EDIT: Trying to comply with @ron-trunk 's request, here is an attempt of a simple "diagram".

```
VPC           -     10.1.0.0/16
   Subnet1    -     10.1.0.0/24   az-1
   Subnet2    -     10.1.1.0/24   az-2
   Subnet3    -     10.1.2.0/24   az-3

   VPN-Subnet -     10.10.0.0/16` az-3  #must be at least /22

   Association: 
   VPN-Subnet - Subnet1

   Route table: 
   cvpn-endpoint-<id>    10.1.0.0/16    <Subnet1-id>  Nat      associate ￼    Active      Default Route  #this is generated

   VPC-IGW    Attached
```

Comment: We need more information in order to help you.  Please provide a simple diagram of your on-prem network along with relevant device configurations.  Without that, we're just guessing.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the actual problem was with the authorization rules. I had set two (as described in the original question), one with open access to everybody, and one with a restriction to a specific group on `10.1.0.0/24`.

The group specified exists - but on IAM. However, the description says something about IDP and/or Active Directory, but no mention of IAM.

I must assume that restricting to a IAM group is unsupported. As soon as I removed that rule (I also falsely assumed that the full-access rule would override this one), things started to work (at least I can connect to my machines. The split-tunnel functionality does not seem to work correctly, in that my global internet traffic on my machine does not work when VPN connected - but that is a different issue).